# Access form enable editing only the last date enter

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there anyway I can restrict user to edit only the last day data in the user form, and disable editing for all other dates, please note that there are several data in same date.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Like making it so only one record showed on the form instead of all records?

Comment: Alter the Record Source property and write some SQL to exclude the data. E.g. Use a where clause

Comment: @newd shows only last date data, might be more than one.

Answer (score 1):

write it in your form VBA

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

if dLast("[YourDateField]" , "[YourTable]") = me.YourFormDate.vlaue then
Me.AllowEdits = True
Else
Me.AllowEdits = False
End if

End Sub
```

Comment: What should I put on YourFormDate?

Comment: Your Date Field Name - the date that you want to control by . Which that used in your form